# Get the data from a websites HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I would like to write a program that would log in to my school's website and check for updates that i should be made aware of. I am relatively new to JavaScript. I looked at the source code for the login page and it appears that the username and password is sent using the `action` attribute. (I tried to find a JavaScript function that is called when the button is pressed , but failed. Also the action attribute is set to a value. ) 
 I Theorize that if i have my login credentials, then if i know the format of the data being sent to the server for verification, i can write a c program that mimics the operation of the login page. How to i see what is being sent ?

Here is the websites code:

```
     <form action="http://[myschoolsdomainname].edu/login/index.php" method="post" id="login">
      <div class="loginform">
        <div class="form-label"><label for="username">Username</label></div>
        <div class="form-input">
          <input name="username" id="username" size="15" value="815008955" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
        <div class="form-label"><label for="password">Password</label></div>
        <div class="form-input">
          <input name="password" id="password" size="15" value="" type="password">
          <input value="Login" type="submit">
          <input name="testcookies" value="1" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

N.B. I am not trying to do anything malicious, i simply want to periodically check the site automatically (using C or Java ) to see if homework has been posted. I like to code and i am curious as to if i can do this , but i am not sure where to begin.

Comment: You can use Chrome's network tab to see the payload being sent to the server. If they did stuff properly, your school will have CSRF protection implemented(it's likely that the CSRF token is being passed in the header, sometimes it's in the payload though), therefore preventing you to be able to do what you want to do though.  You are essentially scraping their website, which most of the time if you look at a website's terms of use is marked as prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nick Delaney - network tab on Chrome (on a mac `Option+Cmd+i`) will show you what you want to see. Click on "Network" at the top of the panel that opens and check the "Preserve log" checkbox (if you don't do this, a full page load will clear out the history).

You should be able to see all the HTTP requests that go into logging in to the site and rendering the subsequent page. CSRF may or may not be an issue, but only experimenting will tell you.

For example, this is the login request for strava.com (a popular site for tracking fitness activities). This tells me that there is a form post passing `email`, `password`, `authenticity_token` (hm, wonder what this is? :), `utf8` and `remember_me` fields. The successful response is a [302 redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to https://www.strava.com/dashboard which also sets some cookies.

[image: strava login request]

If I follow the redirect (the browser automatically does this for us) and look at the dashboard HTTP request (below the currently highlighted request) I will see the HTML that represents the dashboard page for a logged in strava user (me). If the data I want is on the dashboard, the challenge is in making a "correct" login request, following the redirect (with the cookies that were set on the login request) and parsing the response.